# Powershell command as a variable in Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

I am using win_shell module to execute a command op remote host. But ansible is not setting the value the right way (or me of course)

I set a variable that enable or disable scheduled tasks based on user input in Ansible Tower

```
tasks: 
  - name: disable enable tasks without ebs based on user input
    win_shell: '"{{ command_to_execute }}" -TaskName "{{ task_name }}"'
```

the user input in Ansible tower:

```
    - command_to_execute: Enable-ScheduledTask
     or 
    - command_to_execute: Disable-ScheduledTask
```

The job succeded but not enabeling or disableing anything. in the output i can see that:

```
    "cmd": "\"[u'Enable-ScheduledTask']\" -TaskName 
     \"start_something\"",
```

so instead of

```
      Enable-ScheduledTask
```

i get

```
      [u'Enable-ScheduledTask'] .
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got list of one element 'Enable-ScheduledTask' in your `{{ command_to_execute }}` variable. 
The most short and straightforward way would be using `{{ command_to_execute | first }}`

Comment: That seems like an important first step, but note the the  `{{ command_to_execute }}` value is enclosed in  `"..."`. In PowerShell, in order to execute a command whose name is stored in a quoted string, you must prepend  `&`, the call operator: `'& "{{ ... `; alternatively, simply omit the enclosing double quotes in this case.